# Set a parameter for added method to element object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I wrote the method `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` and I know it's in jQuery, but this is some kind of a practice, so I want to add a parameter to the `fadeIn` method:

```js
function fadeIn(e, time) {
  // e.style.opacity = 1;
  var op = Number(getComputedStyle(e).opacity).toPrecision(2);
  e.style.opacity = op;
  if (op >= 1) {
    return;
  }
  e.style.opacity = Number(op) + 0.01;
  setTimeout(function() {
    fadeIn(e)
  }, time)
}

function fadeOut(e) {
  // e.style.opacity = 0;
  var op = Number(getComputedStyle(e).opacity).toPrecision(2);
  e.style.opacity = op;
  if (op <= 0) {
    return;
  }
  e.style.opacity = Number(op) - 0.01;
  setTimeout(function() {
    fadeOut(e)
  }, 10)
}

Element.prototype.fadeIn = function(time) {
  fadeIn(this, time);
};
Element.prototype.fadeOut = function() {
  fadeOut(this);
};
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass in the time at the ongoing calls:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    fadeIn(e, time); // <<<
}, time)
```

Now this is the interval time for increasing the opacity by 1/100, so you might wanna divide the time too:

```
Element.prototype.fadeIn = function (time) {
   fadeIn(this,time / 100);
};
```

So now

```
 el.fadeIn(1000);
```

will take one second to fade in.